# Santax for Joins using Linq/lambda & Nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

Originally I had this linq statement:

```
refusedZones = session.Query<ZoneBO>().Where(x => x.StateId == _config.RefusedStateId).ToList();
```

Works fine and I get my list with business objects. I now need to change this query, I still want my list of strongly typed business objects back, but I have to do a join with another table.

I have tested this SQL query and it works the way I want it to:

```
select z.ZoneName, z.ZoneSerial from zone z join transactionzone tz on z.ZoneId = tz.ZoneId where z.StateId = 3 and tz.StateId = 16
```

My question is how do I do this in linq with a Lambda expression? I assume it will start like this...

```
var refusedZones = session.Query<ZoneBO>().Join(.......expression here....).ToList();
```

Can anyone help me with the santax please, very new to linq, finding it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a reference from Zone to TransactionZone. How have you setup your mappings?

Once you have a reference setup it is unnecessary to explicitly write the joins in LINQ.

You can do this:

```
session.Query<ZoneBO>()
    .Where(x => x.State.Id == 3 && x.TransactionZone.State.Id == 16)
    .ToList()
```